# How to improve performance in ESXI VMs?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, performance-testing, vsphere

I am using **`ESXI`** VMs to install and test my product. When I do the same in physical machine, the installation hardly takes one hour to complete. But when I do the same in VMs, it is taking more than 5 hours. I have the same configuration in both VM and physical machine.

**What could possibly affect the performance in VMs?**

**How can I improve it ?**

Answer (score 0):

Description is very vague (no host server & VM details provided - disk, cpu, memory, networking) to give exact recipe, but there are a few things you need to consider:

- [**memory**](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_performance_mem_vmachine_size.html) and [**number of vCPUs configured**](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010184) for your VM
- disk sub-system configuration (`vmdk` file system hardware and software config are causes of many VMware-related performance problems) IO troubleshootig guide is [**here**](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1008885).

You can also check documentation regarding **[VMware performance troubleshooting](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1008360)**.